# What if we multiply mean of a dependent variable by a constant? A regression

Tags: regression

I have two regressions:

$y_{i} = \beta_{1} \cdot x_{i} + \beta_{0}$ and $y^{*}_{i} = \beta_{1}^{*} \cdot x_{i}  + \beta^{*}_{0}$

$x_{i}$ is the same in both equations, but $\overline{y} = k \cdot \overline{y^{*}}$. In other words, we know the relationship between the means of $y_{i}$ and $y_{i}^{*}$. The question is if also $\hat{\beta}_{1} = k \cdot \hat{\beta}_{1}^{*}$ if the distribution of $y_{i}$ and $y_{i}^{*}$ remains the same (lets say normal distribution)?

My intuition says yes, but I have a problem to prove it. My steps until now:

We know that $\hat{\beta}_{1} = \dfrac{\sum (y_{i}-\overline{y})(x_{i}-\overline{x})}{\sum (x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}} = \dfrac{\sum (y_{i}-k \cdot \overline{y^{*}})(x_{i}-\overline{x})}{\sum (x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}}$ . But now I am a bit lost. Can you help me please? Or at least if my hypothesis that $\hat{\beta}_{1} = k \cdot \hat{\beta}_{1}^{*}$ is correct?

Comment: If $y^{*}_{i}=k y_i$ then $\hat y_i= \beta_{1} \cdot x_{i} + \beta_{0}$ might suggest $\hat y^{*}_{i}= k\beta_{1} \cdot x_{i} +k\beta_{0}$ at least with simple linear regression

Comment: @Henry but $\overline{y} = k \cdot \overline{y^{*}}$ not $y = k \cdot y^{*}$

Comment: @vojtam expectation is linear, so $E[ky] = k\,E[y]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y_i = k\cdot y_i^*$,

$$\hat{\beta}_{1} = \dfrac{\sum (y_{i}-\overline{y})(x_{i}-\overline{x})}{\sum (x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}} = \dfrac{\sum (k \cdot y_{i}^{*}-k \cdot \overline{y^{*}})(x_{i}-\overline{x})}{\sum (x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}}\\
=k \cdot \dfrac{\sum (y_{i}^*-\overline{y}^*)(x_{i}-\overline{x})}{\sum (x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}} = k \cdot \hat\beta_1^*$$